# JPA and Database setup for an association table

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm a little lost on how I should setup my database and entities in jpa for what I'm trying to do.

I have an `Attachments` table which holds uploaded attachment details, like original name uid saved with, date saved, etc.

Several other tables are able to have `Attachments` and more then one per record.

So for every table that can have an attachment I would have an association table with the id and the attachment id.

```
Attachments
-----------
ID 
Original Name
Saved Name


User
-----------
Id
Name

Dog
-----------
Id
Breed
Name

Dog_Attachments
----------------
dog_id
attachment_id

User_Attachments
----------------
user_id 
attachment_id
```

So  I think that's the right way to setup the database... 
But then how do I setup my JPA entities ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class UserEntity  {
     @Id
     private Long id; 
     @Column(name = "Name")
     private String name; 

     ...
     List<Attachment> attachments; 
     ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_attachment")
public class UserAttachment {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id");
    private Long userId;
    @Id 
    @Column(name = "attachment_id")
    private Long attachmentId
    ....
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "attachment")
public class Attachment {

    @Column(name = "id");
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "original_name")
    private Long originalName
    ....
}
```

Is that possible? Or do I have to change the list on user to be a list of User_Attachments and then the user_attachments add a join? Basically can JPA 'flatten' my objects or do I have to

Comment: Can an attachment be referenced by many users / dogs etc? Or is that attachment has only one associated entity?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use relationships in your models. Spring Data JPA takes care of creating the join tables. If you go on to specify the join table entities, then I am afraid you will be unable to leverage the power of Spring Data in a lot of places.

So, you need to create the following relationships:

1. User - Attachment -> One To Many (assuming one user has many attachments, but attachments have a single user)
2. Dog - Attachment -> One to Many (as described above)

For this, you simply need to create the following models: User, Dog, Attachment. You may find this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships#one-to-many-relationship) useful to understand.

Working (sample) example:

```
// @Entity and other annotations
public class Attachment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
 
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String url;

    // add all other fields here, like savedName, dates, whatever
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="attachment_id")
    private User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="attachment_id")
    private Dog dog;
 
    // standard constructor, getter, setter
} 
// @Entity and other annotations
public class User {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Attachment> attachments;

    //...

} 
// @Entity and other annotations
public class Dog {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dog")
    private Set<Attachment> attachments;

    //...

}
```

This will create a bi-directional relationship for you. You may also want to look at uni-directional relationships, where the Many-to-One side of the relationship will not be present. Cheers!